# ng-file-upload function not triggering function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-file-upload

i'm trying to upload a file to my server like, save a path to database and file to folder, for that i tried ng-file-upload here is my code.

```
<form ng-show="divPatient" name="PatientForm" ng-submit="AddUpdatePatient()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly placeholder="Key (Automatic)" ng-model="PatientID" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="FormFocus" name="FirstName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-minlength="3" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LastName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="LastName" ng-model="LastName" ng-minlength="3" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Disease" ng-model="Disease" name="Disease" ng-minlength="3" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phone No." ng-model="PhoneNo" name="PhoneNo" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" class="form-control" ng-model="PhotoURL" required />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="PatientForm.PhoneNo.$dirty && PatientForm.PhoneNo.$invalid || PatientForm.LastName.$dirty && PatientForm.LastName.$invalid || PatientForm.FirstName.$dirty && PatientForm.FirstName.$invalid || PatientForm.Disease.$dirty && PatientForm.Disease.$invalid" />
        <input type="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="CancelForm()" />
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
       <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.FirstName.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
       <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.LastName.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
       <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.Disease.$error.minlength">min 3 letters</span></td>
       <td><span class="eror-text" ng-show="PatientForm.PhoneNo.$error.pattern">Invalid phone no</span></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

here is my Angular code

```
var app = angular.module('StudentApp', ['ngFileUpload']);
app.controller("StudentCtrl", function ($scope, angularService) {

    $scope.selectedFile = [];

    //On file Select
    $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        //This function not running at all ??
        alert("where I'm i ???");
        //$scope.selectedFile = $files;
        //alert($files);
    }

$scope.AddUpdatePatient = function () {
    var file = $scope.selectedFile[0];
    alert($scope.PhotoURL);
    var Patient = {
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Disease: $scope.Disease,
        PhoneNo: $scope.PhoneNo
    };
    var getAction = $scope.Action;

    if (getAction == "Update") {
        Patient.PatientID = $scope.PatientID;
        var getData = angularService.UpdatePatient(Patient,file);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            GetAllPatients();
            alert(msg.data);
            $scope.divPatient = false;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in updating record');
        });
    } else {
        var getData = angularService.AddPatient(Patient);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            GetAllPatients();
            alert(msg.data);
            $scope.divPatient = false;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in adding record');
        });
    }
}
```

My dependencies

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomPlugins").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js",
                  "~/scripts/angular.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/ng-file-upload.min.js"));

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomPlugins")
```

Where did i go wrong, pls tell me how do i upload file to the actionresult using angularjs, thank you

ok i tried onchange

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files)"
```

but i cant send that file to my action result, its showing me null,

```
$scope.selectFileforUpload = function (files) {
    $scope.selectedFile = files;
}

$scope.AddUpdatePatient = function () {
    var file = $scope.selectedFile[0];
    var Patient = {
        FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.LastName,
        Disease: $scope.Disease,
        PhoneNo: $scope.PhoneNo
    };
        var getData = angularService.AddPatient(Patient,filee);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            GetAllPatients();
            alert(msg.data);
            $scope.divPatient = false;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in adding record');
        });
}
```

here is my service code

```
this.AddPatient = function (patient, file) {
    // this showing me file object thats fine
    alert("in services" + filee);
    // i think something wrong here we shouldn't or can't send the file to actionresult like this
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "AddPatient",
        data: JSON.stringify(patient),
        dataType: "json",
        file : file
    });
    return response;
}
```

amd last my action result

```
public string AddPatient(Patient patient,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
         // I'm getting patient data that is fine, but file is showing me null
    }
```

is anything wrong with my service method ??? or do you know how to send form along with files to actionresult or any method in the mvc controller, i heard some pleople do it by using "new FormData", but i dont know that, but i'm willing to learn it or use it, if that solves my problem

Comment: Have you tried debugging to confirm that the function really isn't being called? If you have Chrome, open up the console, go to `Sources`, select your js file, find the `onFileSelect` function and put a `break` on it. Then try uploading a file and see if the function executes

Comment: According to the ng-file-upload readme you should use `ngf-change=fileSelected($file,$event)` instead of your `ng-file-selected`. Did you debug using your console to check if there are any errors? Because if you are using a ng-... that isn't recognized it might break angular entirely

Answer (score 0):

As Guinn mentions in the comments above, the 'ng' that is used for ng-file-upload is not the one in your code.

The symptoms you are seeing definitely match what I have seen happen when the wrong directive is used.

The ng-file-upload git-hb now actually contains some fiddles which you can verify in your browser and then use the same syntax to ensure your implementation works:

- https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#samples